# What all spices and herbs can be used to flavor vinegar?

Tags: vinegar

What all spices/herbs can be included to flavor vinegar. Also want to know which spices/herbs can be paired together in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a matter of taste since someone may think a particular combination works well together  whereas someone else would think it was terrible?

Comment: @JudeI you can tell me what you think fits the best. I would pick things up out of that and find the right combination for me.

Comment: Again, any answer would depend on what purpose you'd use it for. Also what type of vinegar since there are ordinary white vinegar as well as white wine, red wine, malt, apple cider, balsamic and rice vinegars. For me, I'd tend to flavour the vinegar(s) with the same combination as I'd use in the foods I'd pair them with e.g. for salads with Italian foods I'd use similar spices, for Asian salads I'd use spices and herbs used in Asian dishes.

Comment: @Jude I would like to use them in making variety of noodles/pasta recipes probably vegan. Which spices/herbs could be combined for my specific purpose which would lend a different taste and flavor? (Have already tested basil, thyme, rosemary, ginger, garlic and parsley. kindly suggest something apart from them.

Comment: Welcome to the site @SaurabhCooks. Unfortunately this question is both too broad and opinion based. There are thousands of possible combinations and everyone will have their own favorites.

Comment: @GdD I probably know that but I guess, a little help from the pros would go a long way in helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a few suggestions - garlic and tarragon with white wine vinegar; basil, walnuts and garlic; sesame seeds and ginger with rice vinegar (I'd add some soy sauce to the dish too and use bean thread (transparent) noodles rather than wheat pasta; cinnamon and nutmeg with apple cider vinegar.

Do you want more combinations or are these enough?

Comment: Thanks for the combinations. A few more would be helpful.